# For statement pattern matching

Tags: python, if-statement

Pretty new to the world of python so hoping the below is an easy fix or might just be a better way of doing things.

I have written a small piece of code that web scraps a website then stores the information in a list, named below 'lister_info'.

I've then imported the fnmatch module to use a wildcard search on certain words in the strings that are downloaded and stored. I want to go through an if statement to find all the values with the given word but at the moment it just returns the else line of 'nope'. If I run the fnmatch outside of the if statement it returns the correct result and so only failing on the if statement itself.

Where am I going wrong?

```
lister_info =[]

pattern = '*Detached*'
match1 = fnmatch.filter(lister_info, pattern)
pattern2 = '*Semi*'
matching = fnmatch.filter(lister_info, pattern2)
if match1 in lister_info:
    print(len(match1))
elif pattern2 in lister_info:
    print(len(matching))
else:
    print('nope')
```

Comment: `match1` and `matching` are lists themselves. You can loop over and print their values like `for matched in match1: print(matched)`.

Comment: "SCRAP" as a verb means to discard. The word you want is "scape" as in "screenscrape"

Comment: Hmm, I would need more info on how fnmarch works to be sure. But maybe you want to remove " in lister_info" to make it work. Probably that function returns each occurrence of the word, so you can just check if match1 is an empty list.

Comment: @JonSG I've given up on that battle :)

Answer (score 0):

`fnmatch.filter()` returns a list of all matching elements, not a single element. So `in` will never work.

Just check if the list is empty or not.

```
if match1:
    print(len(match1))
elif matching:
    print(len(matching))
else:
    print('nope')
```